# Slick 3.0 bulk insert returning object's order

Tags: scala, jdbc, slick

I want to do a bulk insert using Slick 3.0 ++= function and also using returning to return the inserted objects.

I am wondering whether the return objects (Future[Seq[Something]]) has the same order as my arguments Seq[Something] (without id).

More specifically,

```
val personList: Seq[Person] = Seq(Person("name1"), Person("name2"), Person("name3"))
persons returning persons ++= personList
```

Is the result definitely be Future(Seq(Person(1, "name1"), Person(2, "name2"), Person(3, "name3")))? or can be in other result order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,I believe you are using auto incremented primary key.
I am also doing same as you have mentioned:

```
 case class Person(name: String, id: Option[Int] = None)

 class PersonTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "person") {
    val id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    val name = column[String]("name")
     def * = (name, id.?) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply)
  }

 val personTableQuery = TableQuery[PersonTable]

 def personTableAutoIncWithObject = 
     (personTableQuery returning personTableQuery.map(_.id)).into((person, id) => person.copy(id = Some(id)))

  // insert all person without id  and return all person with their id.
 def insertAll(persons: List[Person]): Future[Seq[Person]] =
   db.run { personTableAutoIncWithObject ++= persons }


//unit test for insertion order:
 test("Add new persons ") {
   val response = insertAll(List(Person("A1"), Person("A2"),   Person("A3"), Person("A4"), Person("A5")))
    whenReady(response) { persons =>
        assert(persons === List(Person("A1", Some(1)), Person("A2",    Some(2)), Person("A3", Some(3)),
    Person("A4", Some(4)), Person("A5", Some(5))))
  }
 }
```

Comment: Note that this only works when the database in question supports it.  For example, MySQL does not support returning the IDs on bulk inserts.

Answer (score 0):

As per I know , the result of the batch inserts are in same order what you are sending to the database and "++=" function will return you the count of records inserted to the table.

Comment: If the code is persons returning person will return the inserted records instead of the count of result. I just want to know if I return the inserted records whether the order will be the same as arguments?